# Is there a WinAPI way to detect remote applications like LogMeIn?

Tags: winapi, web, remote-access

Years ago, there were functions in Win32 whereby the app could check to see if a user was running the app via Terminal Services/Remote Desktop. I thnk it was something like:

```
 GetSystemMetrics(1000H)
```

Is there a system call one can make to check to see if a Win32 or Win64 app is being run remotely via a program like GotoMyPC or LogMeIn?

Comment: I think the call you're referring to is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380798(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Right, but my understanding is that that call only detects Terminal Services and -not- non-MS apps like LogMeIn. I'm wondering if there's a way to detect those as well.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not.  Those are third party apps doing their own video/input capturing and network streaming.  They are plain ordinary apps as far as Windows is concerned.  Terminal Services is built into Windows, which is why there are APIs to query TS status.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can (currently) think of, other than using the [aforementioned API call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380798%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), is *also* seeing if any particular processes you can identify are running (e.g. GotoMyPC or LogMeIn... they will have *some* process running).  Without doing too much research, they *may* be running without actually having someone *using* them.  If, however, they launch something to do the streaming, you could check for *that*.

Just to make sure that this isn't an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what is it that you're trying to do - and perhaps there is another way?

Comment: I'm thinking of an app that is licensed for use on a single LAN. People connecting remotely required a separate license. In the old days, we'd check for Terminal Services and (as you say) for specific processes (Close-Up, Norton). I was wondering if there was a generic way to do this now that there are so many Web-based remote control apps.

Comment: @jchwebdev, can you not require authorisation during a login and do your user-count that way?

Comment: Sure. There are other ways to skin the cat. I was wondering if there was a generic set of APIs that all web remote control programs hook into... as there seems to be for virtual machines. More curiosity than anything else. I see so many of these web remote apps now that I figured there must be some standard 'trick' they all share in common and thus could a general solution for detecting their running.